# PostgreSQL query written millions of times to the log file when using temp files

Tags: postgresql, logging

When a query create temporary files, it writes two entries for each one in the log file. The first one contains the information of the temporary file itself, the second one has the full SQL query. Something like this:

```
2020-05-08 11:02:32 EDT 2020-05-08 10:17:04 EDT 19297 60/837 0 LOG:  temporary file: path "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp19297.3079949", size 297
2020-05-08 11:02:32 EDT 2020-05-08 10:17:04 EDT 19297 60/837 0 STATEMENT:      SELECT ...
```

Sometimes, a query will write millions of small temporary files (for whatever reason it doesn't create a big one). But then the SQL query will be logged all those millions of times in my postgresql-10-main.log file and fill the logs file system.

Is there a way to tell Postgres to log the statement only upon the creation of the first temporary file? I don't want to completely disable this logging as it is quite helpful in identifying and addressing queries that use too much temp space.

My current log configuration is as follows:

```
log_timezone = 'localtime'
log_statement = 'none'
log_duration = off
log_min_duration_statement = 5000
log_line_prefix = '%t %s %p %v %x '
log_checkpoints = on
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
log_lock_waits = on
track_functions = all
log_temp_files = 0
log_autovacuum_min_duration = 0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot configure PostgreSQL to log only first temporary file creation but you can set a temporary file size parameter (note that the log entry is created when the file is deleted and not when it is created).

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-logging.html says

> log_temp_files (integer)
>
> Controls logging of temporary file names and sizes. Temporary files can be created for sorts, hashes, and temporary query results.
>   If enabled by this setting, a log entry is emitted for each temporary
>   file when it is deleted. A value of zero logs all temporary file
>   information, while positive values log only files whose size is
>   greater than or equal to the specified amount of data. If this value
>   is specified without units, it is taken as kilobytes. The default
>   setting is -1, which disables such logging. Only superusers can change
>   this setting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware of that but then I won't be able to tell, from the log file, the right amount of temporary space used by a query.

Comment: You can try to use auto_explain extension with the right setting with `auto_explain.log_analyze = true`: temporary space should be displayed. Note also that if you have a lot of temporary space used by queries it likely means that `work_mem` setting is too small.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was hoping there would be some direct way of controlling this, but I'll limit it using log_temp_files as you suggest. I will rely on pg_stat_statement to analyze temp space usage by queries. Thank you for the bonus suggestion about work_mem, I'll look into that!

Comment: @MauricioPeccorini "I won't be able to tell, from the log file, the right amount of temporary space used by a query"  Your proposal to log only the first file also prevents you from telling that, doesn't it?

Comment: @jjanes, no, I was proposing to log the query line only once not the line with the temporary file information

Comment: @MauricioPeccorini OK.  That does seem like a useful idea.  I'm not sure how to go about implementing it in a way that would be likely to be accepted, though.

Comment: @jjanes I don't really know the technical details that would be required, but the logic would be something like "If the query 'starts' using temporary files, log the temporary file creation (respecting the rule for minimum temp file size) AND log the statement", after that, log only the temporary file creation (again respecting the rule of size)